# Pixelated shadows in Unity

Tags: unity, lighting, shadows

I have tried everything I can think of and all the solutions I could find on forums, but I haven't been able to fix this problem. I have a point light that is shining on several spheres which are casting shadows. The shadows work fine, but they are quite obviously pixelated. How do I get them to be smoother?

These are the settings that I took this screenshot with. I've tried tweaking most of the them, but it's possible I wasn't using the right combination to get the smoother shadows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you played with your camera near and far planes at all? I know for directional lights, keeping a very tight crop between near & far can help cluster the shadow map resolution where you can see it. I don't know whether the same helps with point lights.

Comment: @DMGregory I hadn't tried it, but I just checked and it didn't seem to help. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reaching the upper limits of the built in lights. The alternative is to create your own (rather complicated, it's a combination of shaders, materials and scripting) or find a replacement on the asset store (pretty simple, may be money involved). There are also post processing effects that can help a little at the cost of performance (take a look at [Unity's Post Processing Stack](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/83912) as a starting point).

Unity lights are made for the general cases and they cover a vast majority of use cases, while still having great performance, supporting a large number of lights and producing fairly quality light effects and shadows. But they're not for every use case, if you have a higher standard of quality, you'll probably have to go beyond the built in lights/shadows.